# Hide Category Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a password protected website that shows different posts depending on 
the user roles when you login.

How can I hide a Category Posts for a specific user roles on wordpress?

Comment: Check this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ . It's seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is not the one im looking for. I use wp private content plus plugin but the problem is when i hide the posts it still shows up when i do a search.